# Google Analytics gtag logging wrong custom dimension

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

We are using Google Analytics gtag in JavaScript, but is having problems with the logged data.

We have a tracking code in a .js file we reference on every page. We then call it on 'load' of the page.

The problem is, if go from one URL to a different URL with different relative site URL, it logs the wrong URL in the Custom Dimension field.

For example,

URL: https://example.com/sites/mysite1

- SiteCollectionURL is https://example.com/sites/mysite1
- UserID is 1234

then click a link to another site:

URL: https://example.com/sites/anothersite

- SiteCollectionURL is https://example.com/sites/mysite1
- UserID is 1234

If I debug it and place a breakpoint, SiteCollectionURL has correct value of **https://example.com/sites/anothersite**. Even using Dev Tools -> Network, it passes the correct URL in the "https://www.google-analytics.com/collect" call under cd1 parameter.

Below is the code:

```
function LogGoogleAnalytics(userId) {

    //Format 'UA-{Number}-1'
    var trackingId = 'UA-XXXXXXXXX-1';
    var gaTagScript = document.createElement("script");
    gaTagScript.type = "text/javascript";
    gaTagScript.src = 'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=' + trackingId;
    gaTagScript.async = true;
    document.head.appendChild(gaTagScript);

    window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
    function gtag() {
        dataLayer.push(arguments);
    }

    gtag('js', new Date());

    gtag('config', trackingId, {
        'custom_map': {
            'dimension1': 'SiteCollectionURL',
            'dimension2': 'UserID'
        }
    });

    var siteUrl = getSiteCollectionURL();

    gtag('event', 'pageview_sitecollectionurl', { 'SiteCollectionURL': siteUrl, 'UserID': userId });

}

function LoadGoogleAnalytics() {

    //Do Some Stuff

    //Then Call
    LogGoogleAnalytics(gaUserID);
}

window.addEventListener ? 
window.addEventListener("load",LoadGoogleAnalytics,false) : 
window.attachEvent && window.attachEvent("onload",LoadGoogleAnalytics);
```

Am I missing something here? Is there a caching that gtag uses so it passes 'same' values when redirected to another page?

Comment: Can you post the code for "getSiteCollectionURL()"?

Comment: Also you're not using standard implementation, is there a reason for you to do this?

Comment: Hi XTOTHEL, we are not using standard implementation because we are injecting the javascript file dynamically in the HTML pages.

I have figured it out. Custom Dimension was using "User" scope so it caches the first value logged. I have changed it to "Hit" and it now tracks the value passed per view.